# onKeyUp is not firing when I press most keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard, listener, android

In my Android application, I would like to perform some logic each time a key on the keyboard is pressed, for example, I want to evaluate if they typed a "magic phrase".

To do so, I overrode the method `onKeyUp` in my Activity and experimented to see if it was firing by making it fire a Toast.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Key Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```

The problem is, the Toast is not showing when I press numbers or letters on the keyboard. It is only showing up when `backspace` is pressed. Why is this?

How do I get to work for all keys?

Comment: try with onKeyPress or onKeyDown

Comment: @ankur-singhal There is no `onKeyPress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this by adding a `TextChangedListener` to my `EditText` field.

Here's my simple code, which just makes a little toast appear with the digit count:

```
            EditText passcodeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcodeInput);
            passcodeInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    digitsPressed++;
                    Toast.makeText(Passcode.this, Integer.toString(digitsPressed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```